# Java: get+clear atomic for map

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I would like to implement the following logic:

-the following structure is to be used

```
//Map<String, CopyOnWriteArrayList> keeping the pending updates 
//grouped by the id of the updated object
final Map<String, List<Update>> updatesPerId = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

-n producers will add updates to updatesPerId map (for the same id, 2 updates can be added at the same time)

-one TimerThread will run from time to time and has to process the received updates. Something like:

```
 final Map<String, List<Update>> toBeProcessed = new HashMap<>(updatesPerId);
 updatesPerId.clear();
 // iterate over toBeProcessed and process them
```

Is there any way to make this logic thread safe without synchronizing the adding logic from producers and the logic from timerThread(consumer)? I am thinking about an atomic clear+get but it seems that ConcurrentMap does not provide something like that.
Also, I have to mention that updates should be kept by updated object id so I cannot replace the map with a queue or something else.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: It might work ok with a RWLock. Producers will acquire the lock for read and the consumer the one for write. However, acquiring the lock for read when you actually write something is not intuitive.

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean by "without synchronizing"?

Answer (score 5):

You can leverage the fact that [`ConcurrentHashMap.compute` executes atomically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

You can put into the `updatesPerId` like so:

```
updatesPerId.compute(k, (k, list) -> {
  if (list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
  // ... add to the list

  // Return a non-null list, so the key/value pair is stored in the map.
  return list;
});
```

This is *not* using `computeIfAbsent` then adding to the return value, which would not be atomic.

Then in your thread to remove things:

```
for (String key : updatesPerId.keySet()) {
  List<Update> list = updatesPerId.put(key, null);
  updatesPerId.compute(key, (k, list) -> {
    // ... Process the contents of the list.

    // Removes the key/value pair from the map.
    return null;
  });
}
```

So, adding a key to the list (or processing all the values for that key) might block if you so happen to try to process the key in both places at once; otherwise, it will not be blocked.

---

Edit: as pointed out by @StuartMarks, it might be better to simply get all things out of the map first, and then process them later, in order to avoid blocking other threads trying to add:

```
Map<String, List<Update>> newMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String key : updatesPerId.keySet()) {
  newMap.put(key, updatesPerId.remove(key));
}
// ... Process entries in newMap.
```

Comment: But, since you need to change both places anyway, you might as well wrap the `Map` into a separate class of your own.

Comment: I'd copy the list contents elsewhere and return null from the remapping function, and process the contents later. Processing within the remapping function might take a long time, which could block other threads that might want to update the map.

Comment: @StuartMarks sure. Would `List<Update> thingsToProcess = updatesPerId.remove(key);` be another way?

Comment: Calling `remove()` instead of `compute()`? Might work. I'm concerned about concurrent modification during iteration of the keyset. It won't cause CME, but it might cause entries to be skipped. I'd consider iterating the entryset and calling remove() on the entryset's iterator. That way you already have the value (list of things to process) in hand already without having to do another lookup. Seems a bit cleaner, though more verbose.

Comment: @StuartMarks agreed. I've been toying with editing it into my answer; haven't quite got around to it yet.

Comment: @StuartMarks “without having to do another lookup” applies when you’re iterating over `HashMap.entrySet()`. In case of `ConcurrentHashMap`, there’s no difference between calling `remove()` on the entry set’s iterator or calling `remove(key)` on the map. It’s not even safer regarding concurrent updates. Consider `ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> m = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); m.put("foo", 42); Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = m.entrySet().iterator(); Map.Entry<?, ?> e = it.next(); m.put("foo", 100); System.out.println("removing "+e+" from "+m); it.remove(); System.out.println(m);`…

Comment: @Holger Huh. That's certainly true of the current CHM implementation. It seems unwise to rely on this assumption though. I'd still recommend modification via the iterator, in case the CHM implementation changes, or in case the calling code is modified to use a different map implementation.

Comment: @Holger Also, maybe you should consider using `var` when you put a bunch of code into a comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead of `CopyOnWriteArrayList` as the map value. With COWAL, adds get successively more expensive, so adding N elements results in N^2 performance. LBQ addition is O(1). Also, LBQ has `drainTo` which can be used effectively here. You could do this:

```
final Map<String, Queue<Update>> updatesPerId = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Producer:

```
updatesPerId.computeIfAbsent(id, LinkedBlockingQueue::new).add(update);
```

Consumer:

```
updatesPerId.forEach((id, queue) -> {
    List<Update> updates = new ArrayList<>();
    queue.drainTo(updates);
    processUpdates(id, updates);
});
```

This is somewhat different from what you had suggested. This technique processes the updates for each id, but lets producers continue to add updates to the map while this is going on. This leaves map entries and queues in the map for each id. If the ids end up getting reused a lot, the number of map entries will plateau at a high-water mark.

If new ids are continually coming in, and old ids becoming disused, the map will grow continually, which probably isn't what you want. If this is the case you could use the technique in [Andy Turner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092231/1441122).

If the consumer really needs to snapshot and clear the entire map, I think you have to use locking, which you wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make this logic thread safe without synchronizing the adding logic from producers and the logic from timerThread(consumer)?

In short, no - depending on what you mean by "synchronizing".

The easiest way is to wrap your `Map` into a class of your own.

```
class UpdateManager {
    Map<String,List<Update>> updates = new HashMap<>();
    public void add(Update update) {
        synchronized (updates) {
            updates.computeIfAbsent(update.getKey(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(update);
        }
    }
    public Map<String,List<Update>> getUpdatesAndClear() {
        synchronized (updates) {
            Map<String,List<Update>> copy = new HashMap<>(updates);
            updates.clear();
            return copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is there any way to make this logic thread safe **without synchronizing** the adding logic from producers and the logic from timerThread(consumer)?"

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, I answered that.

Comment: You didn't. You just said "it depends", and then used synchronization.

Comment: @AndyTurner I said "no, it's not possible". The "depends" refers to "whether you mean explicit synchronization by the client", eg via a lock. Note that your answer uses synchronization as well, just hidden.